# CakePHP 3 - validate data not tied to a table (validation without any database involvement)

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

Yesterday I posted a question [CakePHP 3 - Using reusable validators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895489/cakephp-3-using-reusable-validators/) but am still struggling to see how to validate data when it is *not* tied to a particular database table, or set of fields in a table.

What I'm trying to do is upload a CSV file. The data in the CSV may well end up in the database, but *before* any of that happens, I want to validate the file to make sure it's valid - extension is .csv, MIME type is `text/csv`, file size is <1 Mb. This particular validation *has absolutely nothing to do with a database*.

**Where does such validation go, since it's nothing to do with a database table?**

The approach I've used is as follows - but this does not work:

I have a `UploadsController.php` with an `upload()` method. This method handles the upload (form posts to `/uploads/upload`)

I have added the following to my `src/Model/Table/UploadsTable.php` (because I don't know where else to put such code):

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->add('submittedfile', [
            'mimeType' => [
                'rule' => array('mimeType', array('text/csv')),
                    'message' => 'Upload csv file only',
                    'allowEmpty' => TRUE,
            ],

            'fileSize' => [
                    'rule' => array('fileSize', '<=', '1MB'),
                    'message' => 'File must be less than 1MB.',
                    'allowEmpty' => TRUE,
            ]

        ]);

     return $validator;
 }
```

In `UploadsController::upload()` I have this:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    debug($this->request->data['submittedfile']);

    $uploads = TableRegistry::get('Uploads');
    $entity = $uploads->newEntity($this->request->data['submittedfile']);
    debug($entity);
}
```

No matter what file I upload, no errors are returned. Even if I comment-out the entire `validationDefault` method, the behaviour doesn't change.

This is becoming very frustrating as all of the documentation on Cake's website talks about data relating to DB tables. Well, what if you're trying to validate something that's nothing to do with a DB table?

I've opened this as a new question, because the last one doesn't really address this problem.

[Other questions posted about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33432934/cakephp-3-validation-of-uploaded-file-extension) do not address this problem, because in this case they are writing the file info to a DB table, and therefore validating the file *at the same time*. In my case I'm not trying to do that, I just want to validate the file, before considering anything to do with the DB at all. I also want the code to validate a CSV to be re-usable (i.e. not in one specific Controller method) because if I want to check for a valid CSV in 5 different parts of the application, why should I repeat code that does the same thing all over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [a model-less form](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/form.html), it has validation built in, to validate your uploaded file. If you want your validation code to be reusable put it in a trait [or separate class](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#creating-reusable-validators)

In theory you could then do something like this:

```
    $form = new CsvForm();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $result = $form->execute($this->request->getData());
        if ($result && $this->Model->saveMany($result) {
            $this->Flash->success('We will get back to you soon.');
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('There was a problem submitting your form.');
        }
    }
```

Let your form validate the CSV document and return the pure CSV data, or already turn the rows into a set of entites you save.